# Backpropagation algorithm doesn't guess MNIST data at all

Tags: c, algorithm, neural-network, backpropagation

I have been trying to write an artificial neural network that uses backpropagation and I have been trying to train it to recognize digits by using MNIST data. For xor training, this program can complete the training with 63000 epochs. I use 0.5 learning rate for both the weights and biases. For xor, I make only one hidden layer, and 2 neurons for that layer. It seems to work. But when it coems to MNIST, I use 20 neurons and 1 hidden layer, 3 learning rate for both weights and biases (I also tried smaller or higher learning rates but this looked like a good number) but even with 60000 images, it does not come close to guessing numbers. Sometimes it guesses only one number, like 1 4 9, sometimes it doesn't guess anything. I trained it for 450 epochs but it still didn't change anything. The full source code is here: https://github.com/Fethbita/perceptron/blob/master/backprop_mnist_rewrite.c

I thought that there was a problem with my backpropagation algorithm but I couldn't find any after a weeks search. Can you help me finding my problem?

```
// testing the images on the network
// I test by looking at all the outputs and check every number to see if any of them is > 0.9 and if it is, I compare it with the known output of the image.
double outputs_test[number_of_outputs + hidden_layers * hidden];
int correct = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < training_data_size; i++)
{
    feed_forward(train_x + inputs * i, outputs_test, w, bias);
    int maxind = -1;
    int num = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < number_of_outputs; j++)
    {
        int output_n = hidden_layers * hidden + j;
        if (outputs_test[output_n] > 0.9 && maxind == -1)
        {
            maxind = j;
        }
        else if(outputs_test[output_n] > 0.9 && maxind > -1)
        {
            maxind = -2;
        }
        if (train_t[i][j])
        {
            num = j;
        }
    }
    if (num == maxind)
    {
        correct++;
    }
}
printf("Total correct guesses in this epoch = %d\n\n", correct);
////////////////
```

I have these function protoypes and functions.

```
void feed_forward(double* train_input, double* outputs, double* w, double* bias);
int train(double* train_x, double** train_t, double* w, double* bias);
double activation_function(int number_of_weights, const double* w, const double* x, const double* bias);
double sigmoid(double x);
```

I won't write the train function in it's fullest but here is the part that does the backpropagation;

```
int train(double* train_x, double** train_t, double* w, double* bias)
// train_x: the address of the inputs. For example for the MNIST data the first 784 double corresponds to the first image, the second to the second image etc.
// train_t: the address that corresponds to the outputs. Each pointer in the array points to an array of doubles that corresponds to the outputs. For the MNIST data the first pointer points to 10 doubles and if the corresponding image is 4, the double array is like this: [0] = 0.0 [1] = 0.0 [2] = 0.0 [3] = 0.0 [4] = 1.0 [5] = 0.0 [6] = 0.0 [7] = 0.0 [8] = 0.0 [9] = 0.0
// w: the addresses of the weights
// bias: the addresses of the biases
{
    total_error = 0;
    int train_out_index = 0;
    double* train_output;
    for (double* train_input = train_x; train_input < train_x + training_data_size * inputs; train_input += inputs)
    {
        train_output = train_t[train_out_index];

        feed_forward(train_input, outputs, w, bias);
        for (int i = 0; i < number_of_outputs; i++)
        {
            // calculates the error but I don't understand why we multiply it with 0.5
            // If the network guesses every number wrong, the maximum this total_error can be (0.5 for each output neuron, and since there are 10 output neurons, it can be 5 for each input. Since there are 60000 images, it can be 300000 in total. And since we divide it by the number of inputs at the end,) it can be 300000/60000 = 5. But what does this 5 mean? It is 5 if every output the network guesses is wrong.
            int output_n = hidden_layers * hidden + i;
            total_error +=  .5 * (train_output[i] - outputs[output_n]) * (train_output[i] - outputs[output_n]);
        }

        //================= calculates the deltas
        // backward pass
        memset(deltas, 0, (size_t)total_weights * sizeof(double));
        // output layer (hidden to output)
        for (int i = number_of_outputs * hidden; i > 0; i--)
        {
            int a_index = (hidden_layers * hidden) + number_of_outputs - 1 - (i - 1) / hidden;
            int target_index = number_of_outputs - 1 - (i - 1) / hidden;
            deltas[total_weights - i] = (outputs[a_index] - train_output[target_index]) * outputs[a_index] * (1 - outputs[a_index]);
        }

        // rest of the layers
        for (int i = total_weights - number_of_outputs * hidden - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            // first hidden layer (input to hidden)
            if (i < inputs * hidden && hidden_layers > 1)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < hidden; j++)
                {
                    int w_index = inputs * hidden + j * hidden + (i / inputs);
                    deltas[i] += deltas[w_index] * w[w_index];
                }
                deltas[i] *= outputs[i / inputs] * (1 - outputs[i / inputs]);
            }
            // last hidden layer (hidden to hidden) or first hidden layer when there's only one hidden layer
            else if ((i > inputs * hidden + hidden * hidden * (hidden_layers - 2) && hidden_layers > 1) || (i < inputs * hidden && hidden_layers == 1))
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < number_of_outputs; j++)
                {
                    int w_index = (inputs * hidden + hidden * hidden * (hidden_layers - 1)) + j * hidden + (i / inputs);
                    deltas[i] += deltas[w_index] * w[w_index];
                }
                int a_j_index;
                if (hidden_layers == 1)
                {
                    a_j_index = i / inputs;
                }
                else
                {
                    a_j_index = (i - inputs * hidden) / hidden + hidden;
                }
                deltas[i] *= outputs[a_j_index] * (1 - outputs[a_j_index]);
            }
            // other hidden layers (hidden to hidden)
            else
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < hidden; j++)
                {
                    int next_layer_first_index = ((i - inputs * hidden) / (hidden * hidden) + 1) * hidden * hidden + (inputs * hidden);
                    int w_index = next_layer_first_index + j * hidden + ((i - inputs * hidden) / hidden) % hidden;
                    deltas[i] += deltas[w_index] * w[w_index];
                }
                int a_j_index = (i - inputs * hidden) / hidden + hidden;
                deltas[i] *= outputs[a_j_index] * (1 - outputs[a_j_index]);
            }
        }
        //=================

        // update the weights
        for (int i = 0; i < total_weights; i++)
        {
            // update biases
            if (i <= hidden_layers)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    bias[i] -= bias_learning_rate * deltas[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    bias[i] -= bias_learning_rate * deltas[hidden * inputs + (i - 1) * hidden * hidden];
                }
            }
            // first hidden layer (input to hidden)
            if (i < inputs * hidden)
            {
                deltas[i] *= train_input[i % inputs];
            }
            // output layer
            else if (i >= total_weights - number_of_outputs * hidden)
            {
                deltas[i] *= outputs[hidden * (hidden_layers - 1) + i % hidden];
            }
            // other hidden layers (hidden to hidden)
            else
            {
                deltas[i] *= outputs[(((i - hidden * inputs) / hidden) / hidden) * hidden + i % hidden];
            }
            w[i] -= learning_rate * deltas[i];
        }

        train_out_index++;
    }
}


// Feeds one input to the network
void feed_forward(double* train_input, double* outputs, double* w, double* bias)
// train_input: the address of the input to be feeded
// outputs: outputs of each neuron will be written here
// w: weights of the network
// bias: biases of the network
{
    // forward pass
    for (int i = 0; i < hidden * hidden_layers; i++)
    {
        // first layer
        if (i < hidden)
        {
            outputs[i] = sigmoid(activation_function(inputs, w + i * inputs, train_input, bias));
        }
        // hidden layers
        else
        {
            int w_index = inputs * hidden + (i / hidden - 1) * (hidden * hidden) + (i % hidden) * hidden;
            int x_index = (i / hidden - 1) * hidden;
            outputs[i] = sigmoid(activation_function(hidden, w + w_index, &outputs[x_index], &bias[i / hidden]));
        }
    }

    // output layer
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_outputs; i++)
    {
        int output_n = hidden_layers * hidden + i;
        int w_index = total_weights + hidden * (i - number_of_outputs);
        outputs[output_n] = sigmoid(activation_function(hidden, w + w_index, &outputs[(hidden_layers - 1) * hidden], &bias[hidden_layers]));
    }
}

// This function activates one neuron.
double activation_function(int number_of_weights, const double* w, const double* x, const double* bias)
// number_of_weights: the number of weights that is connected to the neuron to be activated
// w: the address of the first weight that is connected to the neuron
// x: the address of the first output of the previous layer
// bias: the address of the bias that is to be added to the weight
{
    double a = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_weights; i++)
    {
        a += w[i] * x[i];
    }
    a += *bias;
    return a;
}

// Sigmoid function
double sigmoid(double a)
{
    return 1 / (1 + exp(-a));
}
```

Comment: 63k epochs to learn xor? That's a lot. Also learning rate of 3 is way too much. I would be hesitant to even go so high as .5 for most problems. But a learning rate of > 1 breaks many statistical assumptions and no longer guarantees convergence for any algorithm.

Comment: I feel reasonably confident learning xor is broken. I would suggest finding a tutorial that shows the calculations by hand for learning xor and mimicking this with your implementation. Check to see if you get exactly the same derivatives they get. Maybe that would help with your understanding of the error function based on your comment in your code.

Comment: Actually that's what I did. I tried to follow this example and the program I wrote gave the same results as he got. https://mattmazur.com/2015/03/17/a-step-by-step-backpropagation-example/ Also the reason I used learning rate 3 is neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap3.html. (*In Chapter 1 we used the quadratic cost and a learning rate of n = 3.0. As discussed above, it's not possible to say precisely what it means to use the "same" learning rate when the cost function is changed...) and I saw it appropriate to use the learning rate as 3.

Comment: Right, so he used a higher learning rate that happened to work so maybe it is okay. I would still be extremely wary of any rate >= 1 as it does break convergence theorems. As for the first link, he says his network has tiny error after 10k epochs on xor, but yours takes 63k. Are you sure they are the same?

Comment: I see. The example uses only one input and one output to train that network and it's not xor. For those inputs, weights and biases, my program works as expected and gives me the same results after 10k epochs. I implemented the xor after that example, so it looks like there might be a problem about the inputs being more than one. (4 for xor, 60k for MNIST) Or it might be about the weights, since the weights in the example are predetermined but for this program they're random (between 0 and 1)